# JPA mongo, fetch many from List

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa

I have a list of string

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add("1");
myList.add("2");
myList.add("3");
```

I want to find db entries by checking a field like this in a loop.

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<MyObject, String> {

    public MyObject findByxfield(String xfield);


}
```

How can I achieve this:

> if Myobject.somefield == myList(i), then I will store MyObject in a
>   List and return it to the user.

Clarification:

Suppose MyObject class has these fields:

```
@Entity
@Document(collection = "MyObject")
public class MyObject{

    private ObjectId _id;

    private String xfield;

    private String somefield;
}
```

I want this kind of functionality in my repository, without for loops:

```
public List<MyObject> findAllBySomefieldList(List<String> somefield);
```

In my application:

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = myRepository.findAllBySomefieldList(myList);
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mongo Template and criteria query by means of the `$in` operator of MongoDB, as follows:

```
@Autowired // if you are using spring, if not just handle it yourself
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;


Query query=new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("somefield").in(myList));
List<MyObject> myObjects=mongoTemplate.find(query, MyObject.class);
```

Of course you must add the spring data mongo dependency in the pom, if you are using maven:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```